# PDFViewCtrl not disposed

Tags: c#, memory-management, xamarin.android, pdftron

We are working on an app using PDFTron. We have noticed that when opening the Activity that displays the allocated memory increases by a lot. After navigating away from the activity only a part of the memory is freed up again. Some PDFtron parts are left behind.

[image]

The problem is that the activity does not seem to finish even though that we have set the activity to NoHistory and singleTask. I have watched some courses on memory management but can't figure out what is cause the activity to remain open.

Before we call `Finish();` on the activity we dispose of the PdfViewCtrl. Then in the OnDestroy:

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    if (_mPdfViewCtrl == null) return;
    _mPdfViewCtrl.Destroy();
    _mPdfViewCtrl = null;
}
```

If the app is used for a long periode of time this results in a out-of-memory error.

```
--- End of managed Java.Lang.Error stack trace ---
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method):0
```

or

```
    --- End of managed Java.Lang.Error stack trace ---
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method):0
 android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:726):0
 android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:703):0
 android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:670):0
 pdftron.PDF.Utils.SignaturePickerDialog$SignatureView.onSizeChanged(SignaturePickerDialog.java:244):0
 android.view.View.sizeChange(View.java:15326):0
 android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:15290):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15201):0
 android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677):0
 android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531):0
 android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677):0
 android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531):0
 android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448):0
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204):0
 android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793):0
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2263):0
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2009):0
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251):0
 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6379):0
 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791):0
 android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591):0
 android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561):0
 android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:693):0
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99):0
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137):0
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493):0
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method):0
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525):0
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209):0
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025):0
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method):0
```

Below a print screen from a simulated session (Android studio monitoring):
[image]

**Edited OnDestroy:**

```
        var old_tool = _mPdfViewCtrl.ToolManager;
        var old_doc = _mPdfViewCtrl.Doc;
        _mPdfViewCtrl?.CloseDoc();
        _mPdfViewCtrl?.CloseTool();
        _mPdfViewCtrl?.Destroy();
        _mPdfViewCtrl = null;
        _mPdfViewCtrl?.Dispose();
        if (old_doc != null)
        {
            old_doc.Dispose();
        }

        if (old_tool != null)
        {
            old_tool.Dispose();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to reproduce using the PDFViewCtrl sample project that comes with the SDK? Or does this only happen in your project?

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for the response. I just received a new link from the pdftron support team. I will test this along this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Activity also has a reference to a PDFDoc object, then you should also dispose of that. This is the recommended way.

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    if (_mPdfViewCtrl == null) return;
    _mPdfViewCtrl.Destroy();
    _mPdfViewCtrl = null;
    if(_mPdfDoc != null)
    {
        _mPdfDoc.Dispose();
    }
}
```

or more generally

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    if (_mPdfViewCtrl == null) return;
    PDFDoc old_doc = _mPdfViewCtrl.Doc;
    _mPdfViewCtrl.Destroy();
    _mPdfViewCtrl = null;
    if(old_doc != null)
    {
        old_doc.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will give it a try and let you know the result

Comment: In the current version we are using _mPdfViewCtrl does not have a method called GetDoc(). The link I received was for the native SDK. Ones I get the Xamarin SDK I will give it a try.

Comment: I've edited my awnser. Would this have the same effect? If so that would not work. I've also added a new monitor session. If this is not the same we would have to wait on the new link.

Comment: I updated the code. In Xamarin there is no GetDoc, just a Doc property.

Comment: I looks like the reference to the doc was the problem we now see far less memory beeing used. I also saw that the android monitor is a bit inaccurate when it comes to xamarin.

Answer (score 3):

From this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/VuTN02dH9ec):

"Q: I have a Page where the user selects files, and another where the user views the Selected PDF. When the user navigates back from the PDF viewing page to the file page, I want to clean up resources used by PDFNet. What is the correct order of cleaning up the Tools, the PDFViewCtrl, and the PDFDoc.

A: You need to call PDFViewCtrl.CloseDoc() first, and then you can call PDFDoc.Dispose().
This is good to put in OnNavigatedFrom for whatever page uses the PDFViewCtrl.

Also, the PDFViewCtrl cannot be disposed manually, instead, we've added a PDFViewCtrl.FreeResources that removes all the underlying structures, which means less memory is used until the garbage collector kicks in.

I like to add the following:

```
        PDFDoc doc = this.PDFViewCtrl.GetDoc();

        this.PDFViewCtrl.CloseDoc();


        if (doc != null)
        {
            await CloseDocAsync(doc);
        }

        this.PDFViewCtrl.FreeResources();
```

Where CloseDocAsync just calls doc.Dispose in a background thread (in case it's a large, complicated document). This might not be necessary, as all document I know of dispose rather quickly. But it doesn't hurt. Even 200 ms of lag on the UI thread might be disruptive.

One thing to keep in mind is that in order for the PDFViewCtrl to be re-claimed by the garbage collector, all events registered to it need to be unregistered. That's why the ToolManager.Dispose() should be called when you navigate away from a page as well.
In that case, just call ToolManager.Dispose before any of the code I added above."

If none of the above helps, you might try re-posting your question in the PDFTron [forum](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/forum.html). The company also has a [tech support option](https://www.pdftron.com/support/maintenance.html) that provides priority tech support. Depending on the version you are using, the tech support might be free.

**EDIT**

The links I gave for the documentation was for the Windows version, not for Android. Here are the Android version links for [PDFViewCtrl](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/Android/?pdftron/PDF/PDFViewCtrl.html) and [PDFDoc](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/Android/pdftron/PDF/PDFDoc.html).

So, the code from the link I gave above won't work for you. What you might try doing instead is simply closing the document. There is a CloseDoc method that can be called off of the PDFViewCtrl class. If this does not work, then try calling the Close method off of the PDFDoc method. The PDFViewCtrl class has a method called getDoc that returns the current document, which is a PDFDoc. The documentation says that the PDFDoc.close method is a destructor. So, try those two ideas.

One other thing I noticed is that there are lock and unlock methods in the PDFViewCtrl class. You might try calling the docUnlock method before calling the close method if the above 2 ideas don't work. The idea being that maybe the call to close would either hang or time out if the document is locked.

Now, if none of that works then is there anything else you are doing that is chewing up memory? Is it possible that you or someone else in your group is forgetting to clean up memory for anything else you might be doing? Is anyone using C++, or perhaps using an API that uses C++ underneath and is neglecting to delete the memory, or call the appropriate close method to clean up properly?

Using a profiler may help answer those questions. There are 3rd party profilers available or you can try the [Microsoft .NET Memory Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx). I don't know if it will work Android. It also requires version 4.5 or higher of the .NET Framework.

There is also a [Xamarin profiler](https://www.xamarin.com/profiler), that is probably a better choice to start with.

Comment: Hi Bob, I will give this a try as soon as I receive a new link. The current version does not have the GetDoc and FreeResources method.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/PDFNet/html/AllMembers_T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl.htm), the GetDoc method is available. Are you using an older version? I did not see FreeResources in the documentation. You might try calling the Dispose(true) overloaded method to release both managed and unmanaged resources. Do this for both PDFViewCtrl and for the [PDFDoc](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/PDFNet/html/AllMembers_T_pdftron_PDF_PDFDoc.htm) object.

Comment: I think so to. I've asked the team for a xamarin link since the link we received was for native android.

Comment: The forum post linked to in the answer here is for PDFNet Windows Mobile (aka Metro, WinRT, UWP). So the API's don't match exactly when it comes to UI elements like PDFViewCtrl which is tightly bound to the OS.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal I have updated my answer and included links for the Android documentation.